# Connecting domain to VPS

Tags: dns, cpanel, vps, nameservers

I am trying to connect my domain tempclassic.co.uk. to my VPS located at 185.151.31.102.

The website is now showing: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN.

Can anyone let me know what has been misconfigured?

Thank you,

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the domain is not using the correct nameservers. Hence, you need to add the correct nameservers provided by the VPS provider in the domain name registrar end or else if the domain name registrar supports DNS pointing add the VPS IP address as a DNS entry to the domain name.